# Print text between pointers

Tags: c++, string, pointers

I have a character range with pointers (`pBegin` and `pEnd`). I think of it as a string, but it is not `\0` terminated. How can I print it to `std::cout` effectively?

- Without creating a copy, like with `std::string`
- Without a loop that prints each character

Do we have good solution? If not, what is the smoothest workaround?

Comment: What's wrong with the copy from `std::string( pBegin, pEnd )`?  That's the natural way of doing it (and the copy won't be noticeable compared to the time taken by the actual output).

Comment: The answer is very useful for me. Maybe I transformed the question too much from the original problem and should have asked about `std::ostream`, which can be `std::stringstream`. where the difference may count.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [ostream::write](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write), which takes pointer and length arguments:

```
std::cout.write(pBegin, pEnd - pBegin);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since C++17 you can use [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view), which was created for sharing part of `std::string` without copying

```
std::cout << std::string_view(pBegin, pEnd - pBegin);
```

`pEnd` must point to *one pass the last character to print*, like how iterators in C++ work, instead of the last character to print

- [What is string_view?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20803826/995714)
- [In C++11 what is the most performant way to return a reference/pointer to a position in a std::string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24761896/995714)

In older C++ standards [`boost::string_ref`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/utility/doc/html/string_ref.html) is an alternative. Newer boost versions also have [`boost::string_view`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/boost/utility/string_view.hpp) with the same semantics as `std::string_view`. Newer C++ standard also has `std::span` which is a little bit similar in purpose. See [Differences between boost::string_ref and boost::string_view](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36704794/995714)

If you use Qt then there's also [`QStringView`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstringview.html) and [`QStringRef`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstringref.html) although unfortunately they're used for viewing `QString` which stores data in UTF-16 instead of UTF-8 or a byte-oriented encoding

---

However if you also need to process the string by some functions that require *null-terminated* string without any external libraries then there's a simple solution

```
char tmpEnd = *pEnd;  // backup the after-end character
*pEnd = '\0';
std::cout << pBegin;  // use it as normal C-style string, like dosomething(pBegin);
*pEnd = tmpEnd;       // restore the char
```

In this case make sure that `pEnd` still points to an element **inside** the original array and not one past the end of it