# C++ passing a file to a string

Tags: c++

Hi i am trying to pass a whole file into a string. This is my Code but the program is always exiting on the first if(). I just can't get behind what i am doing wrong here.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

std::string readFile (std::string filename);

int main() {
    std::string filename;
    std::string Eingabestring;

    std::cout << "Geben Sie eine Datei an" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> filename;
    Eingabestring = readFile(filename);

    std::cout << Eingabestring << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

std::string readFile (std::string filename)
{
    std::string zeile,inhalt ;
    std::ifstream quelle;
    quelle.open(filename.c_str());

    if (!quelle)
    {
        std::cerr << filename << " kann nicht geöffnet werden!\n";
        return exit(-1);
    }

    while (!quelle.eof())
    {
        getline(quelle,zeile);
        inhalt = inhalt + zeile;
    }

    return inhalt;

}
```

Already thanks for your help!

Edit: I just noticed that i put the file into a wrong folder.. But the code still isn't reading the whole file. Just the first line, but i thought with the loop i could get every line of my file into the string?

And i fixed the second return 0 to exit(-1). Thats better right?

Comment: Not this particular issue, but you should read [Why is `iostream::eof` inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong).

Comment: You can still inspect why `quelle.open(filename.c_str());` actually failed using `errno` and `perror()`. There are many reasons why that could happen.

Comment: Most likely the file will not be found because you are entering a *relative* file path like `myfile.txt`. The system will look for the file in the current working directory of the application, which depends on many factors. Try entering the absolute path of the file like `C:\myfile.txt`.

Comment: BTW, `return 0;` from a function that returns a `std::string` is a bad idea.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read whole ASCII file into C++ std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602013/read-whole-ascii-file-into-c-stdstring)

Comment: Ah ok. I am using cLion to code and didn't notice where it build my program and noticed that i put it into a wrong folder.. and i edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than checking to see why the `open()` failed as explained in the comments also keep in mind that there are easier ways to check for when you have hit the end of file in a while loop where you are reading from an `istream`.

The idiomatic way to loop and read from an `istream` in C++ is to embed the read expression that returns a reference to the `istream` in the loop condition, so change your code to

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

int main() {
    auto character = char{};
    auto file_string = string{};
    while (cin.get(character)) {
        file_string += character;
    }

    cout << file_string << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I've used `cin` above but just replace `cin` with your file stream object and everything should work normally.

Note that the while terminating condition is now an `istream` reference, and that is convertible to bool, so the loop will exit when the `istream` object is done reading **or** when the stream encounters any errors besides EOF.  You don't have to check for `eof()` yourself.

Also another thing is to pass strings that you do not intend to modify by const reference instead of by value, so the `readFile()` function should accept a `const string&` instead of a `string`, this will help save you string copying.  When C++17 is available replace that `const string&` with [`std::string_view`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20803826/what-is-string-view)

Comment: _the loop will exit when the istream object is done reading_ ... I would add that the loop also exits if the stream encounters any error besides `EOF`.

Comment: @zett42 updated my answer

Comment: What is the benefit of writing `auto var = type{};` instead of just `type var;` or maybe `type var{};` if you want to make sure to always initialize?

Comment: @zett42 nothing at all, just habit

Comment: @Curious thats not working for me because. I want to read the file line by line and not each character. I actually need to analyze a file and i still don't know how to do it but my professor gave me that while(){} as a hint. So i thought i have to use it. Also i updated my questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this to read your file instead:

```
std::string readFile (std::string filename)
{
   std::ifstream quelle(filename);

   std::string content( (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(quelle) ),
                      (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()) );
   return content;
}
```

Comment: Where did OP say that they were segfaulting?

Comment: He actually returns something from the function, although the first `return 0` is strange.

Comment: @curious I updated this to fit your specifications