# Return a "const char*" as std::string& from a class method

Tags: c++, string, reference

I have a C-Libraray function returning a C-String

```
const char* myFuncC(struct myS *);
```

Now I write a class mapper:

```
class myC {
  private:
    struct myS * hdl
    ...
  public:
    const char* myFunc() {
      return myFuncC(hdl);
    }

  // want to have...
    const std::string& myFuncS() {
      return ??? myFuncC(hdl);
    }
}
```

Now I would like to return a: *`const std::string&`* and I **don't** want to *copy* the C-String pointer data

How I do this?

**update**

Is there a C++ Class who act like a *const C++-String* class and using a *const C-String pointer* as string source ?

I would call this class a *C++-String-External* … *External* mean … using a *external* source as storage… in my case a "const char *"

Comment: I update the example… right I want to have **const std:.string&** as return of the class method.

Comment: You are guessing. Don't. Get a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Why a `const std::string&`?

Comment: Why a reference?

Comment: I don't want to copy the entire string… so i have to return a pointer or a reference… my problem is… how do I create a **std:string** reference from a C-String?

Comment: @AndreasOtto It is unclear what you are asking. Your best bet at this point are the books mentioned above.

Comment: There's no magic that allows you to return a reference without an underlying object it will refer to. And if you wish to avoid dangling reference hell, don't do cargo cult programming with references. Prefer values to references as a default.

Comment: @AndreasOtto you can't, std::string must allocate its own string. You can't get around that by trying to point a std::string& at a c string.

Comment: 1) I update the question: restriction!! → I **don't** want to copy the C-String pointer data
2) Why I need to buy and read a book for such a simple question ?

Comment: Because the very nature of your request shows a misunderstanding of some C++ fundamentals. It's not pointed out as a shortcoming of you personally, but to help you write better C++ in general, and to avoid such headaches in the future.

Comment: I disagree with the comments here, this is a perfectly reasonable question, and a large part of the reason for `std::string_view`’s existence. Just because it’s not possible as OP stated doesn’t make it unreasonable. This question is succinct and answerable.

Comment: @AndreasOtto Because C++ is a strange and complex beast. While things might appear simple on the surface, the underlying complexity requires you to read the book. Then you get the _a-ha_ moment and the entire universe springs into existence.

Comment: I understand that this is a problem… that is the reason why I ask :-)
if I want to write a Wrapper for an existing C-API ... and to be C++ conform
I would like to operate 100% on C++-String… and I understand this is **not**
possible without *expensive* copy "strings" around.

Is this the final answer?

Comment: @AndreasOtto - If you are willing to dispense with `std::string` there are alternatives, yes. I suggest you add into your question a note about who manages the lifetime of the buffer you return.

Comment: @AndreasOtto please don't be so stubborn. A `std::string` is a class, which has all kinds of extra features. Internally the string stores a null-terminated character array (as of C++11). But there is much more in there. You cannot simply interpret a C-style character array as a C++ `std::string`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::string`, by definition, owns its memory and there’s nothing we can do to change this. Furthermore, by returning a *reference* you’re creating a dangling reference to a local variable (or a memory leak).

However, the idea of encapsulating contiguous character ranges in a string-like interface without copying is such a common problem that C++17 added a new type, `std::string_view`, to accomplish exactly that. With it, your code can be written as:

```
std::string_view myFuncS() {
    return {myFuncC(hdl)};
}
```

A `string_view` isn’t a string but it has a very similar API and the idea is to use it instead of many current uses of `string const&`. It’s perfect for the job here.

Note that we are returning *a copy*, to avoid a dangling reference. However, this does not copy the underlying memory, and is cheap — almost as cheap as returning the reference.

Answer (score 1):

Simply return a new string:

```
std::string myFuncS() {
  return std::string(myFuncC(hdl));
}
```

If you really need a refence or a pointer then allocate the string on the heap and return a pointer to it:

```
std::unique_ptr<std::string> myFuncS() {
       return std::unique_ptr<std::string>(new std::string(myFuncC(hdl)));
}
```

Comment: 1. I have a underlying C-API function the C-String is my FIXED restriction.
2. in your example you still copy the C-String to the heap.. I don't want to copy the C-String data at all.

Comment: @AndreasOtto you need to have a copy of the `const char*` into the `string`. Take a look at `string_view` which is what you need (C++17 required) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20803826/what-is-string-view