# Should methods returning const std::string& return const std::string_view instead?

Tags: c++, string, c++17, string-view

Assume we have a simple getter method in a class that returns a `const` reference to a `std::string` member:

```
const std::string& getString() const noexcept { return someString; }
```

With the advent of `std::string_view` in C++17, I wonder whether it has any advantages of writing this instead:

```
const std::string_view getString() const noexcept { return someString; }
```

Does one method have advantages/disadvantages over the other? Clearly (correct me if I'm wrong) both solutions will definitely be better than this:

```
const char* getString() const noexcept { return someString.c_str(); }
```

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50852390/return-a-const-char-as-stdstring-from-a-class-method?noredirect=1&lq=1) related question, but I'm asking for something slightly different.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, you should write:

```
const std::string& getString() const noexcept { return someString; }
```

Instead of (note: not `const`, because never return `const` values):

```
std::string_view getString() const noexcept { return someString; }
```

The reason is - you already have a `string`. So it's not like you have to pay anything extra to get a `string` out of it. And `string` has one notable semantic difference to an arbitrary `string_view`: it's *null-terminated* by guarantee. We know this. Maybe some downstream user needs to rely on that information. If they *need* null-termination (e.g. they need to pass to some C API that requires it) and you give a `string_view`, they have to make a `string` out of it themselves. You save nothing, but potentially make downstream users do more work.

If, however, you had a `vector<char>` instead... then I would suggest to return a `span<char const>` or the equivalent thereof. Since there is no semantic difference and you're just providing a view.

---

There also the separate argument of what:

```
auto x = obj.getString();
```

should do. This either takes a copy of the `string` (expensive, but safe) or effectively a reference to it (cheap, but potentially dangling). But it doesn't entirely look like a reference, it looks like a value. This is a broad issue with reference-semantic types in general (things like `reference_wrapper`, `string_view`, `span`, `tuple<T&...>`, `optional<T&>` if it existed, etc.).

I don't have an answer for this case, but it's something to be aware of.

Comment: Regarding the second part: I think in the `const std::string&` case lifetime extension would kick in, which is probably something you loose when using `string_view`s... would this probably be another argument for preferring a const reference instead of a string view?

Comment: I've seen way too many bugs caused by assuming std::string is null terminated. Unless using c_str() I'd recommend *never assuming*. Sure, it happens to be guaranteed but when changes are made to the code you want the compiler to catch errors, not happily give out pointers to std::vector<char> where someone assumed *v.end() is a legal pointer to a null terminator.

Comment: @andreee lifetime extension will only kick in if your getter returns a prvalue `std::string getString()`. You'll have a dangling reference doing `auto& str = make_obj().getString()`

Comment: @ZanLynx What do you mean? `std::string` [guarantees](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at) null-termination on basically [every](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data) [kind](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) of access since C++11...

Comment: @MaxLanghof All of the bugs happen when you refactor the code to use something *other* than std::string. At that point all of the null termination assumptions *bite you in bad places*. So if it isn't a c_str call don't assume.

Comment: to prevent dangling you can have an rvalue overload of getString which moves out the internal string and a `const&` overload for the normal case

Comment: @FabioFracassi So the rvalue overload returns a `string` and the lvalue one returns a `string_view`? Dunno how I feel about that. (Also, hi Fabio!)

Comment: Hi @Barry , You can, but I would probably return `string` and `string const&`, as the string is already there.

Comment: By returning `const string&`, you are locking yourself into an implementation where you have a dedicated string on hand. Whereas `string_view` is more abstract and allows more freedom within the implementation. In most code you can just flip the return type as needed, but for a more serious contract, I'd recommend `string_view`. It's also very near-free performance wise compared to  `string_view` (returning 2 ptr-size fields instead of 1).