# When should I use std::string / std::string_view for parameter / return type

Tags: c++, string, c++17, string-view

## Introduction

I'm writing some communication application. Before C++17 (without Boost), I use `std::string` and its const reference as `cls1`.

Since C++17, I introduced `std::string_view` to my code as `cls2`.
However, I don't have clear policy when should I use `std::string_view`. My communication application receives data from the network and it is stored to `recv_buffer`. And creates some application classes from `recv_buffer`.

## Construction

If I focus only `cls1`'s constructor, move construction is efficient. But I think that where the parameter `s` from. If it is originally from the `recv_buffer`, I can create `std::string_view` at the receiving (very early) point. And during `recv_buffer`'s lifetime is enabled, use `std::string_view` everywhere. If I need to store the part of `recv_buffer` then create `std::string`.

An only exception I noticed is the `recv_buffer` is always contained complete data for my application class. In this case, move construction is efficient.

## Getter

I think using the return type as `std::string_view` has advantage. Some member function such as `substr()` is efficient. But I don't see any disadvantage, so far.

## Question

I suspect that I might see only pros of `std::string_view`. Before re-writing many codes, I would like to know your ideas.

## PoC code

```
#include <string>

struct cls1 {
    explicit cls1(std::string s):s_(std::move(s)) {}
    std::string const& get() const { return s_; }
private:
    std::string s_;
};

struct cls2 {
    explicit cls2(std::string_view s):s_(s) {}
    std::string_view get() const { return s_; }
private:
    std::string s_;
};

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    // If all of the receive buffer is the target
    {
        std::string recv_buffer = "ABC";
        cls1 c1(std::move(recv_buffer)); // move construct
        std::cout << c1.get().substr(1, 2) << std::endl; // create new string
    }
    {
        std::string recv_buffer = "ABC";
        cls2 c2(recv_buffer);            // copy happend
        std::cout << c2.get().substr(1, 2) << std::endl; // doesn't create new string
    }

    // If a part of the receive buffer is the target
    {
        std::string recv_buffer = "<<<ABC>>>";
        cls1 c1(recv_buffer.substr(3, 3)); // copy happend and move construct
        std::cout << c1.get().substr(1, 2) << std::endl; // create new string
    }
    {
        std::string recv_buffer = "<<<ABC>>>";
        std::string_view ref = recv_buffer;
        cls2 c2(ref.substr(3, 3)); // string create from the part of buffer directly
        std::cout << c2.get().substr(1, 2) << std::endl; // doesn't create new string
    }
}
```

Running Demo: https://wandbox.org/permlink/TW8w3je3q3D46cjk

Comment: Someone asked very similar question few days back: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56601261/should-methods-returning-const-stdstring-return-const-stdstring-view-instea

Comment: Consider string_view as a reference. If the object it refers vanishes, you have a problem.

Comment: Also `std::string_view` lacks all modifier methods `std::string` has (which you don't care about when working with const ref), `std::string::c_str()` also.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`std::string_view` is a way to get *some* `std::string` const member functions without creating a std::string if you have some `char*` or you want to reference subset of a string.

Consider it as a *const reference*. If the object it refers vanishes (or changes) for any reason, you have a problem. If your code can return a reference, you can return a string_view.

Example:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char* a = new char[10];
    strcpy(a,"Hello");
    std::string_view s(a);
    std::cout << s; // OK    
    delete[] a;
    std::cout << s;     // whops. UD. If it was std::string, no problem, it would have been a copy
}
```

[More info](https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/c-17-avoid-copying-with-std-string-view).

Edit: It doesn't have a `c_str()` member because this needs the creation of a \0 at the end of the substring which cannot be done without modification.

Comment: Thank you! I understand about the lifetime. It is similar as `std::string const&` and `std::string_view`. If both possible, and I don't need null termination, I choose `std::string_view`. I decided that is my policy. One exception is complete `std::string` can always be given as the argument of constructor. In this case, I use `std::string` or `std::string&&` as the constructor parameter.

Comment: I guess that I would only use string view when I have to deal with a char*. If I already have a std::string, I would transfer it to a string_view only if I needed a substring.

Comment: Indeed. I generalized my question when I first asked but actual `recv_buffer` is MQTT packet such as https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/os/mqtt-v5.0-os.html#_Table_3.4_- . In this case, I think `std::string_view` based approach is better to get string `a/b` and `c/d` from the `recv_bffer` . It is a kind of substring case as you mentioned.

Answer (score 6):

Don't return a string view when:

- The caller needs a null terminated string. This is often the case when dealing with C API's.
- You don't store the string itself somewhere. You do store the string in a member in this case.

Do realise, that the string view becomes invalidated by operations on the original string such as changing the capacity, as well as if the original string is destroyed. If the caller needs the string for a longer than the life time of the object that stores the string, then they can copy from the view into their own storage.

Comment: Thank you! I understand cons of std::string_view. 1st point is reasonable. I understand that 2nd point means "Don't return a reference of local temporary object.". In this case, return type is `std::string`. Both `std::string_view` and `std::string const&` are bad. Is that right?

Comment: @TakatoshiKondo Returning either string view, or reference to a local string would be bad, yes.