# std::string_view for STL containers

Tags: c++, stl

Here is a great explanation of what a [string_view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20803826/what-is-string-view) object is.

Are there '_view' objects for any of the STL containers besides std::string?

Seems to me that it is an extremely useful thing to have. Imagine a `std::vector_view` class that simply stores a `start` iterator and a `length` field. Not actually owning the underlying data allows for awesome efficiency improvements.

Comment: I think it's useless. Idea is to implement some memory management behind the scene, but usually if you make a copy of vector, you will change it. And thus anyway you need to copy it. And if you don't plan to change it, then you use const pointers or "&" without risk. Of you plan to do it from different threads, then copy usually is much better to avoid any race.
So in the end the use case for such feature is quite rare, but it will add complexity and additional layer in the code.

Comment: @Arkady I respectfully disagree. There is a well defined use case for _view objects. They don't work in every scenario, as you pointed out, but that does not change the fact that in certain situations they can provide great improvements.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a proposal for `span`, which is a view over a contiguous range of objects: http://wg21.link/p0122. See also: [What is a “span” and when should I use one?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45723819/94687).

The GSL library also provides [`gsl::span`](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL/blob/master/include/gsl/span).

---

This might be stretching it, but I also proposed `function_ref`, which is basically a view over a `Callable`:  http://wg21.link/p0792