# Prevent function taking const std::string& from accepting 0

Tags: c++, string, std, implicit-conversion

Worth a thousand words:

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>

class SayWhat {
    public:
    SayWhat& operator[](const std::string& s) {
        std::cout << s << "\n";
        return *this;
    }
};

int main() {
    SayWhat ohNo;
    // ohNo[1]; // Does not compile. Logic prevails.
    ohNo[0]; // you didn't! this compiles.
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler is not complaining when passing the number 0 to the bracket operator accepting a string. Instead, this compiles and fails before entry to the method with:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
  what():  basic_string::_S_construct null not valid
```

For reference:

```
> g++ -std=c++17 -O3 -Wall -Werror -pedantic test.cpp -o test && ./test
> g++ --version
gcc version 7.3.1 20180303 (Red Hat 7.3.1-5) (GCC)
```

**My guess**

The compiler is implicitly using the `std::string(0)` constructor to enter the method, which yields the same  problem (google the above error) for no good reason.

**Question**

Is there anyway to fix this on the class side, so the API user does not feel this and the error is detected at compile time?

That is, adding an overload

```
void operator[](size_t t) {
    throw std::runtime_error("don't");
}
```

is not a good solution.

Comment: Compiled code, throwing exception in Visual studio at ohNo[0] with exception "0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000"

Comment: @pmp Yup, that's the point.

Comment: Declare a private overload of `operator[]()` that accepts an `int` argument, and don't define it.

Comment: @Peter Another good solution I did not think of! Please post it as answer.

Comment: @Peter Though do note it's a **linker** error, which is still better than what I had.

Comment: @kabanus In above scenario, it will be a *compiler* error, because the operator is private! Linker error only if called *within* class...

Comment: @Peter That's especially interesting in scenarios where no C++11 is available – and these *do* exist even today (actually I'm in a project having to deal with, and I'm missing pretty much some of the new features...).

Comment: @Aconcagua You're right, I completely missed that part of the comment, thanks. Sill worth mentioning in case somebody does use it in a class (or when dealing with a function). Peter you should definitely post it for some upvotes, especially with for pre-C++11 readers.

Comment: This has a rough duplicate (looking for broad rejection of `NULL` -> `std::string` conversion) over on the Software Engineering Stack Exchange: [Compile-time checking for NULL initialized std::string](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/309888/215049)

Answer (score 168, accepted):

The reason `std::string(0)` is valid, is due to `0` being a null pointer constant. So 0 matches the string constructor taking a pointer. Then the code runs afoul of the precondition that one may not pass a null pointer to `std::string`.

Only literal `0` would be interpreted as a null pointer constant, if it was a run time value in an `int` you wouldn't have this problem (because then overload resolution would be looking for an `int` conversion instead). Nor is literal `1` a problem, because `1` is not a null pointer constant.

Since it's a compile time problem (literal invalid values) you can catch it at compile time. Add an overload of this form:

```
void operator[](std::nullptr_t) = delete;
```

`std::nullptr_t` is the type of `nullptr`. And it will match *any* null pointer constant, be it `0`, `0ULL`, or `nullptr`. And since the function is deleted, it will cause a compile time error during overload resolution.

Comment: This by far is the best solution, completely forgot I can overload a NULL pointer.

Comment: in Visual Studio, even "ohNo[0]" throwing a null value exception. Does it mean a implementation specific of std::string class?

Comment: @pmp What is thrown (if anything) is implementation specific, but the point is the string is a NULL pointer in all of them. With this solution you will not get to the exception part, it will be detected at compile time.

Comment: @pmp - Passing a null pointer to `std::string`'s constructor is not allowed by the C++ standard. It's undefined behavior, so MSVC can do whatever it likes (like throw an exception).

Answer (score 29):

One option is to declare a `private` overload of `operator[]()` that accepts an integral argument, and don't define it.

This option will work with all C++ standards (1998 on), unlike options like `void operator[](std::nullptr_t) = delete` which are valid from C++11.

Making the `operator[]()` a `private` member will cause a diagnosable error on your example  `ohNo[0]`,  unless that expression is used by a member function or `friend` of the class.

If that expression is used from a member function or `friend` of the class, the code will compile but - since the function is not defined - generally the build will fail (e.g. a linker error due to an undefined function).

Answer (score 3):

#### Using string_view helps (somewhat)

As of C++17, we have the [`std::string_view` class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20803826/1593077). It is intended exactly for this use-case, of passing non-owning references-to-string-like-objects, to functions which only read a string. You should seriously consider using it for this kind of operators.

Now, `std:: string_view` has its own set issues (See: [enough `string_view` to hang ourselves with](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xwP4YCP_0q0)), but here it will give you a useful warning. If you replace:

```
    SayWhat& operator[](const std::string& s) {
```

with

```
    SayWhat& operator[](std::string_view s) {
```

and you compile with `--std=c++17 -Wall`, you get:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:16:11: warning: null argument where non-null required (argument 2) [-Wnonnull]
   16 |     ohNo[0]; // you didn't! this compiles.
      |           ^
```

Comment: I think this would be the preferable solution in  read only case, such as my mock example - maybe even any `const string&` function argument. I think most of the "dangling" issues would be moot in these cases (without some effort to break things on purpose).