# Can I use std::string* argv as main function argument?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, argv, argc

Usually I see:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
```

But can I use:

```
int main(int argc, std::string* argv)
```

instead?

If it's not possible how can I convert  `char*` to `std::string`?

PS: I am using **`C++11`**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`main` argument must be `char** argv` or `char* argv[]`.

[[basic.start.main]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.start.main#2)

> *2. An implementation shall not predefine the `main` function.
> This function shall not be overloaded.
> Its type shall have C++ language linkage and it shall have a declared return type of type `int`, but otherwise its type is implementation-defined.
> An implementation shall allow both*
>
> *(2.1).
> **a function of `()` returning `int` and***
>
> *(2.2).
> **a function of `(int, pointer to pointer to char)` returning `int`***

---

What you can do is to convert the arguments in the code by using one of the following:

- Simply assigning it:

```
    if(argc > 1)
    { 
        std::string str = argv[1]; 
    }
```

- Constructing the string using the argument as the constructor parameter:

```
    std::string str(argv[1]);
```

- With initializer list:

```
    std::string str{argv[1]};
```

---

If you'd like to keep a collection of the arguments I would suggest keeping them in a variable size container `std::vector` using one of the following:

- Constructing vector in place using `std::vector` constructor, here using pointers to the beginning and to one past the end the array of strings `argv` as constructor arguments:

```
    std::vector<std::string> strs(&argv[1], &argv[argc]); //*
```

- Using initializer list:

```
    std::vector<std::string> strs{&argv[1], &argv[argc]}; //*
```

- Adding the arguments in a loop:

```
    std::vector<std::string> strs;

    for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++) //*
        strs.push_back(argv[i]);   
    }
```

*Not including `argv[0]` program name.

Answer (score 3):

No, but you can create a `std::vector<std::string>` by using the `vector` [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) that takes iterators:

```
template< class InputIt >
vector( InputIt first, InputIt last, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
```

So to put the arguments (excluding the program name) in a `vector`:

```
std::vector<std::string> args(argv + 1, argv + argc);
```

To separate your ordinary `main` from your enhanced `main` you could do it like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int cppmain(std::string program, std::vector<std::string> args) {
    std::cout << program << " got " << args.size() << " argument(s):\n";

    for(auto& arg : args) { // each argument as a string
        std::cout << " " << arg << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    //
    //         string from char*
    //                |
    //                V
    return cppmain(argv[0], {argv + 1, argv + argc});
    //                      ^                     ^
    //                      |                     |
    //                     vector<string> from char*[]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### No, but there has been some discussion of this in standards committee

In Paper [P0781](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0781r0.html), Erich Keane suggests having the standard allow for the following:

```
int main(const some_container<const some_string_type> args){
  for (auto Arg : args) {
    // some usage of this character array...
  }
}
```

There's the question of which container and which string type should be used.  Mr. Keane suggests an `initializer_list` of `string_view`'s - not `std::string`'s, because the latter ones require a bunch of resources, while [string_view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20803826/what-is-string-view)'s are very lightweight.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. But you can use something like the following to store them as `std::string`s

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc,char** argv){
    std::vector<std::string> strings(argc-1);
    for(size_t i{}; i < strings.size();++i){
        strings[i] = std::string{argv[i+1]};
    }
    for(const auto& el :strings)
        std::cout << el << " ";


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does `size_t i{}` mean?

Comment: @klutt It's uniform value initialization. [See](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization)

Comment: @klutt it declares a variable named `i` of a type `size_t` and initializes it via `{}`, that is - with `0`.

Comment: So basically just `size_t i=0` then?